# Using a counter to increment a column number

Tags: sql-server, counter

I need to increment a column (Counts) +1 for every NEW DocNumber. So if the DocNumber is the same for three columns, the counter will be 1,2,3 etc. Below is the code. I got it to the point where it will update the entire table, just not based on the same or different docnumbers. Can someone help me with the logic here?

Basically, I want to restart the counter when it hits a new TempDocNumber

```
DECLARE @DocTable Table (DetailID FLOAT, TempDocNumber FLOAT, Counts INT)
INSERT INTO @DocTable (DetailID, TempDocNumber, Counts)
SELECT DetailID, DocumentNumber, 0 FROM ChargebackDetailTempTable


declare @Counter int
Set @Counter = 0
Update @Doctable
SET @Counter = counts = @Counter + 1

-- start counter over when new tempdocnumber
```

Comment: In this case you shouldn't need an update at all. But in general, please don't use this "quirky update" pattern. It's not supported, not documented, could break with a new version or service pack, and in the form you have does not guarantee order of processing (especially since your @table doesn't have a key or clustered index).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just create your insert like this:

```
DECLARE @DocTable Table (DetailID FLOAT, TempDocNumber FLOAT, Counts INT)
INSERT INTO @DocTable (DetailID, TempDocNumber, Counts)
SELECT  DetailID, 
        DocumentNumber TempDocNumber, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DocumentNumber ORDER BY DetailId) Counts
FROM ChargebackDetailTempTable
```

No `UPDATE` needed.

**For SQL Server 2000**

Assuming that DetailID is an identity column, you can try the following (again, no `UPDATE` needed):

```
DECLARE @DocTable Table (DetailID FLOAT, TempDocNumber FLOAT, Counts INT)
INSERT INTO @DocTable (DetailID, TempDocNumber, Counts)
SELECT  DetailID, 
        TempDocNumber,
        Counts = (  SELECT COUNT(T1.DetailID) + 1
                    FROM ChargebackDetailTempTable T1
                    WHERE T1.DetailID < T.DetailID and T1.TempDocNumber = T.TempDocNumber)
FROM ChargebackDetailTempTable T
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using sql 2008 which complicates things a bit. I am not able to use row_number or else I would have a long time ago.

Comment: @user1049984 Are you using SQL Server 2000?

Comment: I believe it is 2003. Whichever version it is, it does not support row update.

Comment: @user1049984 The version is important. There is no SQL Server 2003, it can be SQL Server 2000, 2005, 2008...And by row update, you mean `ROW_NUMBER`?

Comment: Yes it is 2000. And yes I mean row_number. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @user1049984 I updated my answer with a solution for SQL Server 2000

Comment: Are you sure that is correct? Isnt the @DocTable supposed to be used somewhere in the bottom select?

Comment: @user1049984 I am using it, I'm inserting the values on that table. Can't you test this solution with a limited dataset?

Comment: TempDocNum should be DocumentNumber. That is my fault. It works like a charm. Thanks!!!